# Testing Platform Cache usage

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, platform-cache

When writing Apex test cases for code that utilizes the [platform cache](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_cache_namespace_overview.htm) what are the important scenarios I need to cover?

Additionally, how would I address those is the test methods?

For instance, can you adapt the test cases based on the partitions capacity.

Answer (score 10):

The first and most obvious scenario is the handling of a cache miss and hit. It appears that the [local cache](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_internals.htm) in testing context is isolated. So it will always start out empty. The exact method of testing will depend on implementation, but generally you could either:

1. call the same code twice in succession to first miss and populate the cache. Then subsequently hit the cache. Ideally assertions would be made that the results are the same and that the [cached result was faster](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_best_practices.htm) (as measured via elapsed time).
2. Use two independent test methods. One that asserts the expected the result when the cache misses. The other that explicitly inserts into the cache before calling the method so a hit will occur.

Assertions can be made via [`getMissRate()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_cache_Partition.htm#apex_cache_Partition_getMissRate) about the expected outcome.

Other scenarios to consider:

1. Is the code optimized to retrieve multiple keys from the cache in one call. Ref. [Group Cache Requests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_best_practices.htm)
2. Does the code correctly handle hitting the Cache Partition Size Limit.
3. Does the code correctly handle attempts to cache items that exceed the Local Cache Size Limit.
4. Does the code correctly handle attempts to cache items that exceed the Single Cached Item Size limit. Will be thrown as a `Cache.ItemSizeLimitExceededException` exception. See [`getMaxValueSize()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_cache_Partition.htm#apex_cache_Partition_getMaxValueSize)
5. Will all items generate valid alphanumeric cache keys. See [`validateKey()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_cache_Partition.htm#apex_cache_Partition_validateKey) and similar methods.
6. What happens if there is no capacity allocated to the partition - [How can I detect that a packaged Platform Cache Partition has no capacity allocated?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/299037/102)

Comment: I'm going to try and evolve this answer as I work through it. Contributions or independent answers welcomed. For instance, there will be a number of special considerations around Session partitions that I haven't covered.